# Converting a vector of ranges into combination of sets in Python

Tags: python, set, range, combinations

In Python, I have a list of ranges like that:

```
A = [range(0,2),range(0,4),range(0,3),range(0,3)]
```

First I have to convert all of these ranges into sets. I can create an empty set and add the resulting list to it. I would have:

```
B = [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

But after that, I have to create all the possible combinations of elements between the lists. The set with the lowest values would be [0, 0, 0, 0] and the highest values would be: [1, 3, 2, 2]. It would be a combination of 2x4x3x3 = 72 sets. How can I achieve this result, starting with the list of ranges (A)?

Comment: a set in python is like this {0,1} using curly brackets. Simple brackets are lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `itertools` module to take the cartesian product of all the `range` objects in `A`, and skip making `B` altogether:

```py
import itertools
A = [range(2), range(4), range(3), range(3)]
list(itertools.product(*A))
```

Output (skipping some items for readability):

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 1),
  .
  .
  .
 (1, 3, 2, 2)]
```

Verifying the length:

```py
>>> len(list(itertools.product(*A)))
72
```

Note that `itertools.product()` yields `tuple` objects. If for whatever reason you'd prefer these to be lists, you can use a comprehension:

```py
[[*p] for p in itertools.product(*A)]
```

Another approach, as @don'ttalkjustcode points out, is that you can avoid creating `A` entirely and skip directly to the cartesian product via the `map()` function:

```py
list(itertools.product(*map(range, (2, 4, 3, 3))))
```

However, this assumes that all your ranges start at 0.

You could generalize this mapping technique by using a `lambda` which will create range objects from a list of tuples:

```py
>>> list(map(lambda t: range(*t), ((6, -3, -1), (0, 3), (5,), (10, 1, -2))))
[range(6, -3, -1), range(0, 3), range(0, 5), range(10, 1, -2)]
```

Comment: Could even do `product(*map(range, [2, 4, 3, 3]))`.

Comment: Since you're using itertools anyway, you [could also use starmap](https://tio.run/##nY1BCgIxDEX3PUWWqVSwFkUED5PBUQttU9JsPH1tB8G9gfzw@PBS3/riEi5Ven8IZ4i6ijKnBjFXFoWmJJmqMQQ3SLEpDsJEebkT6BWEynPFnVoHiGcH@zDWTzo4CPOe3Ew/0I/qaMeYKrEokv1Zv39w8/3l6v0D).

Comment: Thank you! It really worked using built-in itertools.

Comment: @ChrSld glad I could help. Go ahead and accept the answer if you're satisfied. That way your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

to get the Cartesian product do the following :

```
A = []
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(4):
        for k in range(3):
            for n in range(3):
                combo = [i,j,k,n]
                A.append(combo)
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you're using incorrect terminology. Your code doesn't produce combinations, it produces the cartesian product.

Comment: I think he wants all possible combination from all ranges .And I verify my script and it produces len(A) = 72.

Comment: No, what they are describing is a cartesian product, which your code also produces. I'm saying that you're just calling it by the wrong name. Your code is correct, but it's not combinations, it's the cartesian product.

Comment: @ddejohn So if I have four shirts and three pants, I'm not allowed to say I have 12 combinations I can wear? I must say the cardinality of the cartesian product of shirts and pants is 12? Rather ridiculous. Was perfectly fine the way it was.

Comment: When "combinations" has a very specific meaning in the context of combinatorics, yeah I think it's reasonable to let people know when they use incorrect terminology because it can cause confusion. Casually using the word "combination" is fine in the context of every day life, but not when you're talking about counting.